# Función para reconocer un texto de un elemento, pero, diferente? Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una duda, acerca de como estoy trabajando ahora para un addon (así los llamamos en mAuthor, un gestor de contenidos....) que emplea jquery y necesito lo siguiente pero no doy con la tecla...

Necesito reconocer un texto, dentro de un elemento bien sea un H5 o un div y que al encontrar ese texto, me aplique una clase, y actualmente estoy usando éste:

```
jQuery('#scan:contains("arriba")').next('div').addClass('cd-top');
jQuery('#scan:contains("abajo")').next('div').addClass('cd-bottom');
jQuery('#scan:contains("izquierda")').next('div').addClass('cd-left');
jQuery('#scan:contains("derecha")').next('div').addClass('cd-right');
```

Estoy buscando dentro de ese id, que si contiene esa palabra, "arriba", o la que sea, me aplique en el siguiente div una clase que ahí nombro.

Como tengo que sacar más de un addon (o llamados módulos) de éstos, que va a contener idéntico código, es decir, un clon, si saco 3 addons va a buscar en los 3 a la vez la palabra que hayamos escrito en lugar de forma individual. En otros addons, para que no se "propague" aquello que yo hago uso antes de cerrar una función:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Pero sin éxito en éste caso, no puedo tener 4 addons y en cada uno poner "arriba, "abajo", "izquierda" y "derecha" para que se comporten de forma individual, si cargo más de uno, deja de funcionar.

La cuestión y perdonad el tostón, es, como llamo a éste código...

```
jQuery('#scan:contains("arriba")').next('div').addClass('cd-top');
```

En lugar de ese id que sea algo así?:

```
$('#scan').text(function(){
    if($(this).contains("loquesea")...addClas('')..{
...hacer lo que sea...
} else if {....
});
```

Es difícil de explicar como funciona mAuthor pero es la única forma de que al cargar más de un addon o módulo en pantalla, tengan individualidad (y luego meter un stopPropagation si se pudiera).

Sabríais como acabar ese código?

P.D un addon es como una mini web, no puedo usar en cada addon diferentes ids o clases, cuando sacas uno, se replica el código.

Comment: No me queda muy claro lo que buscas. Estás creando addons que van a tener código repetido, pero sólo quieres que ese código repetido se ejecute una vez, ¿es eso correcto?

Comment: Buenos días, si algo así, el problema de mAuthor es que no puedes tener 4 divs por ejemplo por la "web", sino que sacas unos addos creados que llevan su html, estilos y Js.... 

El problema es que necesito sacar depiendo del trabajo, hasta 6 ó 7. y al haber más de uno, el código se pisa de unos a otros y no funciona. Si sacas uno, si, sino, no.

Comment: Uf que difícil de expresarse jeejje, si saco 4 addons. tienen 4 htmls, 4 estilos idénticos, su Js etc... Son independientes pero tienen mismos ids, etc.... entonces, lo de "arriba, abajo, izquierda etc... " es un texto qe yo meto a tiempo real para que el objeto apunte a la dirección que le mande (porque así lo puse en sus clases independientes) pero éste código no funciona más que con 1... no puedo cargar más de dos y que funcione correctamente.

Perdón, ignora el comentario anterior que se me pasó el tiempo, éste si. Mil gracias!.

Comment: Hola @djohny creo que tu problema comienza con que en html tener dos ids identicos en el documento es [ilegal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/id). Podrías empezar usando clases para identificarlos en su lugar. Todo esto depende de cómo creas los addons (por ejemplo en un iframe) o insertados en el documento pero no das muchos detalles sobre esto en tu pregunta. En lugar de usar selectores como `$('#scan')` puedes usar `$(this).find('.scan')` suponiendo que puedas determinar el elemento contenedor de tu addon. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes,

si te he entendido bien, podrías utilizar algo como lo siguiente:

```
if($('#scan').contains('arriba')){

   $(this)..next('div').addClass('cd-top');

}else if($('#scan').contains('abajo')){

   $(this)..next('div').addClass('cd-bottom');

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado,
Saludos

Comment: Buenas tardes a los dos. Juan, hay una forma que si puedo usar que lo coge correctamente, por ejemplo, si es una función al hacer click, tal y como mencionas:

$(this).next('div').addClass('laquesea);

Esto si lo acepta porque no estoy realmente pisando una y otra vez ids.

Gracias Eric, probaré tu código y te cuento algo :) algo similar probé pero acabado en .length de otros ejemplos que encontré por la web. No obstante me guardo el script :D gracias!.